# Google Calendar API Sync with python website

Tags: google-calendar-api, outlook-calendar

1. We have python website where events are created by users.
2. We want to sync the created events on python website on google calendar based for logged user email address (calendar attached with logged in user email address)
3. To show these events on calendar we need to call (event create/ event update /event delete ) Api's based on user email address

Please suggest if any documentation available.

Comment: Please suggest if there is any solution for outlook calendar

Comment: Refer the following link for creating managing deleting events in google calendar   
  https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events. For Google OAuth refer link https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth

Comment: Also have a look at this quickstart for Python: https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python